# How to obtain a caller object reference from within a called method?

Tags: java

I have to execute a given String as JavaScript code, e.g. `eval('Foo.setMessage("Hello!")')`, from within a class called `Engine`. Here, `setMessage()` is a public static method of the `Foo` class. Because I want to access some properties of the `Engine` object from within the `setMessage()` method, how can I obtain a reference to the `Engine` object?

I do know how to get the caller class name using `Reflection` or `CurrentThreadStack` or `Throwable` (see the code below), but these do not return a caller object reference.

//----------------------------------------------------------------

@John: I have followed your four steps and made the following code. However, in the `Foo` class, I cann't get the right `Engine` object which is calling the `setMessage()` method. Thanks.

```
import javax.script.*;

public class Engine {
    public static ScriptEngine scriptEngine = new ScriptEngineManager().getEngineByName("ECMAScript");
    public String engineName;
    public String message;

    public Engine(String name) {
        this.engineName = name;
    }

    public void eval(String script) {
        try {
            Engine.scriptEngine.eval(script);
            //to do something more
        } catch (ScriptException e) {
            System.out.println(e.toString());
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Engine firstEngine = new Engine("First engine");
        Engine.scriptEngine.put("firstEngine", firstEngine);
        firstEngine.eval("Packages.Foo.setMessage('Hello!');");

        Engine secondEngine = new Engine("Second engine");
        Engine.scriptEngine.put("secondEngine", secondEngine);
        secondEngine.eval("Packages.Foo.setMessage('Hello!');");
    }
}

public class Foo {
    public static void setMessage(String msg){
        Engine myEngine = (Engine)Engine.scriptEngine.get("What engine to get: first engine or second engine???");
        myEngine.message = msg;
        System.out.println(myEngine.engineName);
    }
}
```

Please help, thanks,
John

Comment: Is this a JavaScript or Java question??

Comment: @gath: it may be a Java question but one may give me a JavaScript solution. I don't know. Thanks.

Comment: Mixing Java and JavaScript... GWT? Rhino?

Comment: OK what is your Java environment?

Comment: OK I can see from your note on an answer that you are using `sun.org.mozilla.javascript...` which is also known as Rhino, for future reference.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

**Step 1**: Expose the current script engine as a global variable. 
**Step 2**: Save your engine object in the script engine.
**Step 3**: Pass the engine object as parameter from javascript.
**Step 4**: Get your engine instance from `Foo.setMessage(SctriptEngine,String)` method.
**Step 1:**

```
    // expose the current script engine as a global variable
    scriptEngine.put("scriptEngine", scriptEngine);
```

**Step 2:**

```
    //save your engine object
    scriptEngine.put("myEngine", /*YourEngine instance*/);
```

**Step 3:**

```
var imps = JavaImporter(java.io,java.util,/*imports*/);
with(imps){

    Foo.setMessage(scriptEngine,"message");
}
```

**Step 4:**

```
public class Foo {
    // save ScriptEngine instance if you don't want to pass it as parameter
    public static void setMessage(ScriptEngine engine,String msg) {
        YourEngine myEngine = (YourEngine)engine.get("myEngine");
        // use myEngine...
        // or
        // ScriptContext sc = engine.getContext();
        // YourEngine myEngine = (YourEngine)sc.getAttribute("myEngine");

    }

}
```

**UPDATED**: keep the same key name(e.g. myEngine) for all `Engine` objects. Also it is good to prefix key name with **current thread name** or **id** as long as the resultant key name is unique across threads.

```
String keyName = Thread.currentThread().getName() + "myEngine";
```

or

```
String keyName = Thread.currentThread().getId() + "myEngine";//preferred
```

Comment: I have followed your steps and made the following code. However, in the `Foo` class, I cann't get the right `Engine` object which is calling the `setMessage()` method. Thanks.

Comment: @John: is this a single threaded application? if it is so, keep same key name for all engines.so the last `put` call overrides the exiting engine.

Comment: if it is a multithreaded application, save the current thread name as a prefix in your engine key.

Comment: Oh, yes, it is a multithreaded application. Good workaround! I got it. Thank you very much! solved!

Comment: @John: From [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq):`When you have decided which answer is the most helpful to you, mark it as the accepted answer by clicking on the check box outline to the left of the answer.This lets other people know that you have received a good answer to your question`.

Answer (score 5):

You cannot get caller's "this", if you mean that.

Answer (score 2):

If the caller is needed at a method, pass it as a parameter?

Comment: Could you please give more detail on how to pass the caller as a parameter in `eval('Foo.setMessage("Hello!")')`?

I have try `eval('this, Foo.setMessage("Hello!")')`, then `this` will reference to something like `sun.org.mozilla.javascript.internal.NativeObject`, not the `Engine` object which is what I need.

Comment: John the fundamental problem is that Java and JavaScript are different languages running in different environments. You can't trivially pass object references from one to the other. You can define a JavaScript interface for your Java object using Rhino, or you could devise a JavaScript version of your Java object and use JSON to pass parameters needed to build it.

Comment: @Jim: just talking in pure Java, somehow can I obtain a reference to the caller object (i.e. here the `Engine` object) from inside the `setMessage()` method of the `Foo` class?

Comment: There are two huge problems to overcome to get that information, firstly, even getting 'this' from the caller appears to be impossible in Java, secondly you're crossing a language barrier. If you are able to modify `setMessage` you may be able to add a parameter which is the Java object. Contrary to my last reply it may be easier to mix Java and JS in Rhino than I had thought. There's an article on it here. http://www.mozilla.org/rhino/tutorial.html It's still advanced stuff though. I don't want to discourage you but it may be better to take a step back and get some opinions about how best to

Comment: ... achieve the goals of your application.